# How to call direct pdf download api with auth token in react-native using axios

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I am callind a api which is directly download pdf and perfectly work in postman but not work in react-native application with axios.

I also tried to call with blob format but i am getting error which is  **Cannot create URL for blob!**

```
     axios({
      method: GET,
      url: url,
      responseType: 'blob',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/pdf',
        "x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest",
        Accept: "application/pdf",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
   .then(response => {
        const file = new Blob(
          [response.data], 
          {type: 'application/pdf'});
          const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
          window.open(fileURL);
      })
      .catch(err => { 
        isDev && console.log('error we got back', err);

      });
```

and without blob format i am getting this bellow values in response:

```
"03123 00000 n 
0000015836 00000 n 
0000024222 00000 n 
0000000289 00000 n 
0000002463 00000 n 
0000002483 00000 n 
0000002529 00000 n 
0000002581 00000 n 
0000002633 00000 n 
0000002956 00000 n 
0000002820 00000 n 
0000002697 00000 n 
0000003019 00000 n 
0000003468 00000 n 
0000006174 00000 n 
0000003244 00000 n 
0000003448 00000 n 
0000006195 00000 n 
0000006455 00000 n 
0000014634 00000 n 
0000015056 00000 n 
0000014613 00000 n 
0000015972 00000 n 
0000016237 00000 n 
0000023223 00000 n 
0000023575 00000 n 
0000023202 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 32
/Info 1 0 R
/Root 17 0 R
>>
startxref
24461
%%EOF
```

"

Comment: can you please follow this link: https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743

Comment: tried but getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const {config, fs} = RNFetchBlob;
 let DownloadDir = fs.dirs.DownloadDir;
   let options = {
      fileCache: true,
    addAndroidDownloads: {
        useDownloadManager: true,
        notification: true,
        title: `${name} file report`, 
        path: DownloadDir + `/${name}Report` + '.pdf',
        description: 'Downloading file.',
      },
    };
    config(options)
          .fetch(
            "GET",
            url,
            {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
            },
          )
      .then(response => {
        console.log('The file saved to ', response .path());
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(' response in catch123', err);
        return reject(err);

      });
```

Comment: Weren't you looking for an axios solution?